# C - How to search for a pattern in a binary .dat file?

Tags: c, file, search, design-patterns

My program searches by the names of people registered in the system.  For example, when I search by "Fu", the program will display all the information of users who have the pattern "Fu" in their names.  The main problem is that the program is detecting how many people have the default set in the search, but it is displaying repeated information. I suppose I am manipulating the file in the wrong way.

[Use the people.dat file for you to test the program](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GwF6NZ16e2LA98Imnz_IKXQpjnCfllTg)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct pes Pes;

struct pes {

    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int numero_uf;
    int uf;
    char nome[101];
    char enderCid[101];
    char enderBair[101];
    char numCasa[51];
    char cpf[12]; 
    char tel[13];
    char email[31];
    char login[51];
    char senha[51];
    char c;
    char status;

};

void exibePessoasEncontradas(Pes** usuarios_encontrados, int quantidade);

int main (void) {

    FILE* fp;

    Pes* cadastro_pess;
    Pes** usuarios_encontrados;

    int i;
    int aux;
    int tam;
    int achou;

    char procurado[100];
    char resp;

    fp = fopen("pessoas.dat", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Ops! Ocorreu um erro na abertura do arquivo!\n");
        printf("Não é possível continuar o programa...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    system("clear");

    printf("\n =================================");
    printf("\n | | |  Programa Biblioteca  | | |");
    printf("\n =================================");
    printf("\n >>>       BUSCA PESSOA        <<<");
    printf("\n =================================");
    printf("\n");

    printf(" Informe o nome da pessoa a ser buscada: ");
    scanf(" %100[^\n]", procurado);

    i = 0;
    aux = 0;
    achou = 0;

    cadastro_pess = (Pes*) malloc(sizeof(Pes));

    while(fread(cadastro_pess, sizeof(Pes), 1, fp)) {

      i += 1;

    }

    fclose(fp);

    FILE* fp2;
    fp2 = fopen("pessoas.dat", "rb");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        printf("Ops! Ocorreu um erro na abertura do arquivo!\n");
        printf("Não é possível continuar o programa...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    tam = i;
    usuarios_encontrados = (Pes**) malloc(tam * sizeof(Pes*));

    char *ret;

    while(fread(cadastro_pess, sizeof(Pes), 1, fp2)) {

      for(int j = 0; j < strlen(procurado); j++) {

        ret = strchr(cadastro_pess->nome, procurado[j]);

        if((ret != NULL) && (cadastro_pess->status == '1')) {

          usuarios_encontrados[aux] = cadastro_pess;

          aux += 1;

          achou = 1;

          break;   
          // continue;  

        }

      }

    }

    fclose(fp2);

    if (achou) {

        exibePessoasEncontradas(usuarios_encontrados, aux);

    } else {

        printf("\n %s não foi encontrado(a)...\n", procurado);

    }

    printf("\n Digite algo e tecle ENTER para continuar.\n\n");
    scanf(" %c", &resp);

    free(cadastro_pess);

    return 0;

}

void exibePessoasEncontradas(Pes** usuarios_encontrados, int quantidade) {

  for(int k = 0; k < quantidade; k++) {

    int dia = usuarios_encontrados[k]->dia;
    int mes = usuarios_encontrados[k]->mes;
    int ano = usuarios_encontrados[k]->ano;
    int numero_uf = usuarios_encontrados[k]->uf;

    printf("\n\n Nome: %s \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->nome);
    printf(" CPF: %c%c%c.%c%c%c.%c%c%c-%c%c \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[0], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[1], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[2], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[3], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[4], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[5], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[6], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[7], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[8], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[9], usuarios_encontrados[k]->cpf[10]);

    printf(" Data de nascimento: %d/%d/%d \n", dia, mes, ano);

    printf(" Email: %s \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->email);
    printf(" Login: %s \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->login);
    printf(" Senha: %s \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->senha);
    printf(" Telefone: %s \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->tel);

    if(numero_uf == 1) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Acre";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 2) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Alagoas";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 3) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Amapá";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 4) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Amazonas";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 5) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Bahia";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 6) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Ceará";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 7) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Distrito Federal";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 8) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Espírito Santo";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 9) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Goiás";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 10) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Maranhão";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 11) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Mato Grosso";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 12) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Mato Grosso do Sul";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 13) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Minas Gerais";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 14) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Pará";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 15) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Paraíba";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 16) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Paraná";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 17) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Pernambuco";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 18) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Piauí";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 19) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Rio de Janeiro";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 20) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Rio Grande do Norte";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 21) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Rio Grande do Sul";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 22) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Rondônia";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 23) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Roraima";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 24) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Santa Catarina";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 25) {
        char nome_uf[] = "São Paulo";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 26) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Sergipe";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    } else if(numero_uf == 27) {
        char nome_uf[] = "Tocantins";
        printf(" Estado: %s \n", nome_uf);
    }

    printf(" Cidade: %s \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->enderCid);
    printf(" Bairro: %s \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->enderBair);
    printf(" Numero da casa: %s \n", usuarios_encontrados[k]->numCasa);
    printf("\n");

  }

}
```

Comment: `usuarios_encontrados = (Pes**) malloc(tam * sizeof(Pes*));` So you allocate space for `tam` *pointers*. In your read loop you read your data into your previously allocated structure pointed to by `cadastro_pess;` , then store that pointer into the matching array slot with `usuarios_encontrados[aux] = cadastro_pess;`. You never, however, allocate a *new* structure for another read. All your reads go into the same structure. And that address is repeated in each and every table slot. The last item read will be the only one that is "in" the table, because all table slots lead to that address.

Comment: Edit: You are right, this is the solution for my problem. Really  thanks thanks very much! I edited the code and it worked as I wanted.

Comment: while(fread(cadastro_pess2, sizeof(Pes), 1, fp2)) {

      for(int j = 0; j < strlen(procurado); j++) {

        ret = strchr(cadastro_pess2->nome, procurado[j]);

        if((ret != NULL) && (cadastro_pess2->status == '1')) {

          usuarios_encontrados[aux] = cadastro_pess2;
          
          aux += 1;
          achou = 1;

          auxiliar = (Pes*) malloc(sizeof(Pes));

          cadastro_pess2 = auxiliar;

          break;   
  
        }
      
      }

    }